# Why += works in a swift playground but not in the swift app?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, addition

Why you can use += in a swift playground but not in the swift app? So - where is the problem? If I write += in the app - there comes the error ‚Type ‚()‘ cannot conform to ‚View‘‘

App:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        var addUp = 0
        addUp += 2 //error
    }
}
```

Playground:

```
var addUp = 0
addUp += 2 //adds 2
```

But there is no problem in the playground. Do you know why? And how I can use it in the app?

Thank you!

Comment: But that isn’t the same code, don’t you see the difference?

Comment: Yes I do, but @JoakimDanielson - how can I use += or something like this in a view?

Comment: You can’t, that is why you get an error. Views are for building and displaying the UI. You have to keep your computational code outside of them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the `var addup = 0` inside of the VIEW

move the addup variable declaration outside the scope of `var body: some view {}`

you need to actually return a view like below. This returns a ScrollView

```
   var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ///code in here
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank u for helping out @JulianSilvestri but I try it - it came the same error